# Change Bitnami Jenkins base root URL

Tags: apache, tomcat, jenkins, bitnami

I've installed Jenkins with bitnami image on google cloud. However I want to change base root path from /jenkins to / but I can't do it until the moment. I've tried with bnconfig --appurl / but isn't working. Any idea?

Comment: Could you please confirm this is the bnconfig command you executed?
`sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/bnconfig --appurl /`

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I have executed. Also, afte that, I restarted apache but still not working. When I access into the root path I'm being forwarded to /jenkins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitnami developer here.

In order to move jenkins to root you should do this:

- First, modify the contend of the `/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/conf/httpd-app.conf` to make apache don't serve jenkins in `/jenkins`. The content of the file should be this:

  ```
             ProxyRequests     Off
             ProxyPreserveHost On
             AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
             <Location />
             ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/ nocanon
             </Location>



  # App url redirect
  # RewriteEngine On
  # RedirectMatch ^/$ /jenkins/
  ```

> Note that you should open the file with root privileges, for example
>   `sudo vim httpd-app.conf`

Then, you should go to `/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/webapps`
Inside that folder you should have  3 files:

```
ROOT (folder)
jenkins.war
jenkins (folder)
```

Now you should delete the `ROOT` folder:

`sudo rm -rf ROOT`

And move the `jenkins` folder to `ROOT` folder:

`sudo mv jenkins ROOT`

Also, in order to make that works you have to create a file in 
`/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost` called `ROOT.xml`

The content of that file should be:

```
<Context>
  <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

Then, you should restart all the services with:
`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart`

And then you should be able to access to jenkins in `/`